# Number of monomials of certain degree

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomials) says that the number of different monomials of degree $M$ in $N$ variables is $$\frac{(M+N-1)!}{M!(N-1)!}\; .$$ Can anyone explain why this is true?

Answer (score 22):

It's counted by a method known as [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29).

Think of it this way, you have $M$ 'powers' that you can assign with repetition to any of the $N$ variables. Lay out your $M$ 'powers' in a line. Then you choose to insert $N-1$ bars between different powers. Each bar marks a cut off, so for your first bar, all the powers to the left will be applied to the first of $N$ variables, and then all the powers to the right of the first bar and the the left of the second bar will be the powers applied to the second of the $N$ variables and so on.

There are $\binom{M+N-1}{N-1}$ to do this, as you essentially have $M+N-1$ spots to put your $M$ powers and $N-1$ bars, and you choose $N-1$ spots to put down your bars, and fill all the remaining spots up with powers. But $\binom{M+N-1}{N-1}=\frac{(M+N-1)!}{M!(N-1)!}$, and you get your formula.

Answer (score 19):

Represent say $x_1^3 x_2^2 x_4^2 x_5$ ($N=5,M=8$) by $***|**||**|*$. Out of $M+N-1$ places we need to choose $N-1$ $|$'s (or $M$ $*$'s) - so we get $M+N-1$ -choose- $N-1$.