# Let $I = (X,Y) \subset k[X,Y]$ then $\dim_k(k[X,Y]/I^n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

Why we have this:

> Let $I = (X,Y) \subset k[X,Y]$ then $\dim_k(k[X,Y]/I^n) = 1+2+3+...n =
> \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

This is no clear for me.

Comment: Do you understand the counting problem you are solving? You need only determine the number of monomials in two variables of total degree less than $n$. Hence you want to count $(i,j)$ that produce $X^iY^j$ with $i+j<n$. This is a triangular lattice and the counting $1+\cdots+n$ gives the desired dimension.

Comment: how you do the triangulate lattice? Can you say a example for example with $dim_k( k[x,y]/I^3)$ please

Comment: Did you try the case $n=1$ before posting?

Answer (score 2):

Simply
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1},\,I^n=(x,y)^n=(x^iy^j\mid i,j\in\{0,1,\dots,n\},\,i+j=n),
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{K}[x,y]_{\displaystyle/I^n}=\mathbb{K}[x,y]_{<n}=\{f\in\mathbb{K}[x,y]:\deg f<n\};
$$
a base of this $\mathbb{K}$-vector space is $\{x^iy^j\mid i,j\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\},\,i+j<n\}$, and its size is $\displaystyle\binom{(n-1)+2}{2}=\binom{n+1}{2}=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$.

For some proof of this formula, you can read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378417/p-nx-y-denote-the-vector-space-of-polynomial-with-degree-less-than-equal-to?noredirect=1&lq=1)!